# Calling ts. function from HTML to change its parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a ts. function in my component.ts for reading data out of JSON file. This take a number as a parameter which is responsible for specifying the data read of the JSON file. I want to "control" this parameter from HTML (component.html). What I really want is to use a select tag and by choosing one I call that ts. function. (e.g. I have 3 options in that select tag and each of them  call the function but with different parameter)

I've tried using this for calling that function: {{myFunctionName}} or using a button tag but it doesn't do what I want.

component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

function(param1: number) {...} 

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.function(1); 
   }
}
```

//currently I call this function here but I cant change the parameter when the program is running so that's why I want to control it in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that in your .ts file

```
myFunction(param: number) {
// fetch your data or whatever you want to do;
fetchData(param) 
}
```

You have to call `myFunction` in your .html file. As you mentioned you want to do this with the select

```
<select (change)="myFunction($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let i of options">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```